# Multithreading in C using Mutex Locks, Suspicious behaviour

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

currently i am trying out multihreading in c. Up to now things are going well but currently i am experiencing an issue i can not understand.

In order to get a sense for using pthread_mutex_lock and _unlock i have made up an exemplary and simple scenario where paralleism obviously takes place. Code is attached and should be suitable to give it a try.

As the source code below shows a tries to pour out its total amount of 10 units and the one drinker is consuming everything that will be offered. Since the cup can only contain 5 units maximal, a mutex variable is used to regulate this exemplary exchange.

Everything works fine but i do not understand the strange output on console. The output is listed below. Does anybody have an idea of what is going wrong? Or is everything fine? I'm totaly out of ideas. There i appreciate your help.
Your jBug.

```
Stomach: 0

Jug: 10

End: 0
call waiter 0 auf
call drinker 0 auf
Content of Cup 0 waiter Content of Cup 1
Content of Cup 1 waiter Content of Cup 2
Content of Cup 2 waiter Content of Cup 3
Content of Cup 3 waiter Content of Cup 4
Content of Cup 4 waiter Content of Cup 5
Content of Cup 5 drinker Content of Cup 4
Content of Cup 4 drinker Content of Cup 3
Content of Cup 3 drinker Content of Cup 2
Content of Cup 2 drinker Content of Cup 1
Content of Cup 1 waiter Content of Cup 1 drinker Content of Cup 2
Content of Cup 1
Content of Cup 1 waiter Content of Cup 1 drinker Content of Cup 2
Content of Cup 1
Content of Cup 1 waiter Content of Cup 1 drinker Content of Cup 2
Content of Cup 1
Content of Cup 1 waiter Content of Cup 1 drinker Content of Cup 2
Content of Cup 1
Content of Cup 1 waiter Content of Cup 1 drinker Content of Cup 2
Content of Cup 1
Content of Cup 1 drinker Content of Cup 0

Stomach: 10

Jug: 0

End: 0
```

feel free to try it yourself.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//structs für kellner
typedef struct kellnerstruct {
    int krug;
    int becherkapaz;
    pthread_mutex_t* myMutex;
} kellnerinfo;

//structs für trinker
typedef struct trinkerstruct {

    int becherkapaz;
    pthread_mutex_t* myMutex;
 trinkerinfo;

//Konkurrenzkampf findet hier statt
int becher = 0;

//param ist struct und enthät infos.
void* kellner(void* param){
    kellnerinfo* myStruct = (kellnerinfo*)param;
    while(myStruct->krug!=0){
        pthread_mutex_lock(myStruct->myMutex);
        while(myStruct->krug!=0 && myStruct->becherkapaz!=becher){

            printf("Content of Cup %d waiter ",becher);
            becher++;
            myStruct->krug--;
            printf("Content of Cup %d\n",becher);

        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(myStruct->myMutex);
    }
    return NULL;
}

//param ist struct und enthät infos.
void* trinker(void* param){
    trinkerinfo* myStruct = (trinkerinfo*)param;
    while(myStruct->magen != 10){
        pthread_mutex_lock(myStruct->myMutex);
        while(myStruct->magen != 10 && becher!=0){

            printf("Content of Cup %d drinker ",becher);
            becher--;
            myStruct->magen++;
            printf("Content of Cup %d\n",becher);

        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(myStruct->myMutex);
    }
    return NULL;
}

//allocate threadinfo struct
kellnerinfo* getKellnerPtr(int anzahlthreads){
    kellnerinfo* p = malloc(anzahlthreads*sizeof(kellnerinfo));
    return p;
}

//allocate threadinfo struct
trinkerinfo* getTrinkerPtr(int anzahlthreads){
    trinkerinfo* p = malloc(anzahlthreads*sizeof(trinkerinfo));
    return p;
}

int main(void) {
    /**
     * Alloziere und initialisiere struct
     *
     *
     *
     */
    //init mutex becher
    pthread_mutex_t becherSperre;

    //init structs
    kellnerinfo *kellnerPtr = getKellnerPtr(1);
    //setze Zeiger von struct auf initialisierten mutex
    kellnerPtr->myMutex = &becherSperre;
    kellnerPtr->krug = 10;
    kellnerPtr->becherkapaz = 5;

    //init structs
    trinkerinfo *trinkerPtr = getTrinkerPtr(1);
    //setze Zeiger von struct auf initialisierten mutex
    trinkerPtr->myMutex = &becherSperre;
    trinkerPtr->magen = 0;
    trinkerPtr->becherkapaz = 5;

    /**
     * Threads starten
     *
     *
     *
     */
    //Kellern Arbeitsbeginn
    printf("\nStomach: %d\n",trinkerPtr->magen);
    printf("\nJug: %d\n",kellnerPtr->krug);
    printf("\nEnd: %d\n",becher);

    int anzahlKellner = 1;
    pthread_t myKellner[anzahlKellner];
    for (int i=0; i<anzahlKellner; ++i){
        fprintf(stderr,"call waiter %d auf\n",i);
        if (pthread_create(&myKellner[i], NULL, kellner, (void*)(kellnerPtr) )) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error creating thread\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    //Trinker Arbeitsbeginn
    int anzahlTrinker = 1;
    pthread_t myTrinker[anzahlTrinker];
    for (int i=0; i<anzahlTrinker; ++i){
        fprintf(stderr,"call drinker %d auf\n",i);
        if (pthread_create(&myTrinker[i], NULL, trinker, (void*)(trinkerPtr) )) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error creating thread\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    /**
     * Join beider Gruppen
     *
     *
     *
     */

    for (int i=0; i<anzahlTrinker; ++i){
         //wait for the second thread to finish
        if (pthread_join(myTrinker[i], NULL)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error joining thread\n");
            return 2;
        }
    }

    for (int i=0; i<anzahlKellner; ++i){
         //wait for the second thread to finish
        if (pthread_join(myKellner[i], NULL)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error joining thread\n");
            return 2;
        }
    }

    printf("\nStomach: %d\n",trinkerPtr->magen);
    printf("\nJug: %d\n",kellnerPtr->krug);
    printf("\nEnd: %d\n",becher);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Well, start by properly initializing your mutex before starting up the threads. That certainly couldn't hurt. `pthread_mutex_t becherSperre = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;` Something tells me checking the results of `pthread_mutex_lock` rather than assuming it always works wouldn't hurt either. And personally I'd latch the mutex until all threads are in place.

Comment: you released my pain and solved this issue. the results now looks perfect. thank you very much. now i can go on in becoming familiar with pthreads!

Comment: Of topic: `(void*)(kellnerPtr)` -> `(void*)(&kellnerPtr[i])`. Same for trinkerPtr. BTW: Using English names for variables and functions  are typical a good habbit.